# Возможно ли добавить плавной в данной ситуации?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Привет сделал простой аккордеон.

```
<div class='item'>
<div class='submenu'> submenu<div>
</div>
```

Логика простая submenu скрыто при клике на item добавляется класс active и в стилях `item.active{display: block}`
Только отсуствует плавность. Возможно ли добавить, либо соит изменить стили как то ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство `display` [неанимируемо](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Но необходимого вам эффекта можно добиться при помощи изменения свойства [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) (тоже неанимируемо) и [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity), которое анимировать можно.

Пример:

```js
var t = document.querySelector(".box");

setInterval(() => {
    t.classList.toggle("active");
}, 1000);
```

```css
.box {
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
    padding: 1rem;
    
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    
    background-color: red;
}

.box.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Block</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поиграться высотой:

```
.item .submenu {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.4s all;
}
.item.active .submenu {
    height: auto;
}
```

Либо на jQuery можно повесить событие на `click`

```
$("item").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('.submenu').slideToggle();
})
```